# columns of indefinite orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The columns of an orthogonal matrix form an orthonormal set (one can take this as an equivalent definition of $O(n)$). What is the analogous statement for, say, $O(p,q)$, the orthogonal group of the indefinite form  of signature $(p,q)$,
$$
\langle x,y\rangle = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + \dots + x_py_p - x_{p+1}y_{p+1} - \dots - x_{p+q}y_{p+q}
$$
$O(p,q)$ can be defined as the square matrices in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ satisfying
$$
A^{-1} = I_{p,q}A^TI_{p,q}
$$
where $I_{p,q} = diag(1,1,\dots,1,-1,-1,\dots,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D=I_p\oplus iI_q=\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,i,\ldots,i)$. Then $DAD$ is a complex orthogonal matrix. Therefore the columns of $DAD$ form an orthonormal set with respect to the dot product (*not* inner product) in $\mathbb C^{p+q}$.

Comment: I see that DAD is complex orthogonal. I checked in a few examples and it seems that the columns of DAD forming an orthonormal set wrt the dot product is equivalent to saying that the columns of A form an orthogonal set with respect to the bilinear form of signature (p,q) and which has p columns of (p,q) magnitude 1 and q columns of magnitude -1. Is this correct?